# How to show an alert before leaving the table view.?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uialertview

I am working with a master detail application. In the master section records are listed, and detail section shows each record details. The detail section is a table view where we can edit each record. the problem is that "**while editing a record,if i tap a record on the other side, any changes that i have made on the original record are lost and new record details are shown in the table view"...**
can anyone please tell me how to show an alert that asks for "**save or cancel**" , before **"showing the new record details"**..

Answer (score 0):

> any changes that i have made on the original record are lost

A common rule in developing applications is

> **NEVER** loose the user's work

So it would maybe just be the best idea to just save what the user changed.

But let's head to your actual question:

> can anyone please tell me how to show an alert

I think you mean those alters looking like push notifications with two buttons.
You create them with UIAlertView.
Then in the alert's delegate you can figure out which button was pressed and you can decide how to go on. Just check out the documentation for UIAlertView - it's pretty simple :)

Comment: Yeah its simple i know,, but i also mention that "the alert should display before the new record details are shown" Here what happens is the alert box is displayed, but i lose the changes that i made.. i mean that when displaying the alert, its also necessary to privent further navigation..

Comment: You could create a boolean property for every record. Whenever the user changes something you could set it to yes - otherwise no. Now in the method that is responsible for displaying a record you could figure out if that changed boolean is true - in that case you could to what is necessary and afterwards proceed to display the new record as before.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:LString(@"ISCO_FLOW_CALC") message:LString(@"DELETE_MESSAGE") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:LString(@"CANCEL") otherButtonTitles:LString(@"SAVE"), nil];
        alert.tag=11;
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if(buttonIndex==1 && alertView.tag==11)
    {
        //your save data action;
    }
    if(buttonIndex==0 && alertView.tag==11)
    {
        //your Cancel data action;
    }
}
```

Comment: It displays the alert after the new record details are shown... so i lost all changes that i made..

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to your DetailViewController in the MasterViewController
eg. in your MasterViewController.h:

```
DetailViewController *detailVC;
```

Set this reference to your most recent DetailViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and always check if it is not nil before showing a new detailVC

```
DetailViewController *controller=[[DetailViewController alloc] init]; //Or similar
if (detail){
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save or Cancel"  message:@"Save or Cancel" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save",nil];
    [alert show];
}
else{
detailVC=controller;
//Show controller
}
```

Now show the new detailViewController after the user tapped a button of the UIAlertView:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if (buttonIndex==0) { //Tapped cancel
   //show detailVC
}
else{ //Tapped save
 //save
 //Show detailVC
}
}
```

Hope this helps